# Angular Material version for Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am working on a project that is using Angular v 8.2.14, and would like to use the controls provided by Angular Material.

I have attempted to use Angular Material, but the default version of Angular Material installed by ng is version 9, which I am seeing apparently will not compile with Angular 8.

What version of Angular Material works with Angular 8?

Comment: The version 8.2.3.

Comment: Why not use the latest version of angular ? Update your app using the `ng update` command.

Comment: Because I have a lot of code written in Angular that I reuse in new projects. Unfortunately, the Angular folks have a bad habit of making major changes in new Angular versions that break libraries in older versions. To upgrade versions would force me to rewrite a lot of code, something which defeats the purpose of frameworks like Angular!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use version 8.2.3

here is the link to version 8 docuementation
https://v8.material.angular.io/

Answer (score 6):

you can use version 8.2.3

run this command `npm install @angular/material@8.2.3` or `npm i @angular/material@8.2.3`.

here `i` is short version of `install`.

Comment: thank you, but where can i find compatibility table for angular and angular material ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use version 8.2.3.

Here is the link for an online tool to find compatible versions of related NPM packages - [npmpeer.dev](https://www.npmpeer.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

I m using the version @angular/CLI version :

Package                         Version

angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.8
angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.8
angular-devkit/core            14.2.8
angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.8
angular/cdk                    14.2.6
angular/cli                    14.2.8
angular/material               14.2.6
schematics/angular             14.2.8
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.7.4

despite that when i install:

ng add @angular/material....
doesnt install me the packages of

angular/cdk  14.2.6
angular/material  14.2.6

but it doesnt install both at the same time, i needed to install one by one, step by step.